# Running Time of an Algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, big-o

Sorry this is a three part question. I keep trying to get the first part, and I think that if I get that the rest will fall into place, but my running time isn't quite right. I understand that there are n iterations, but not how to calculate the inner loop's number of iterations without using value j

Consider the following basic problem. You’re given an array A consisting of n integers A[1], A[2], ...A[n]. You’d like to output a two-dimensional
n-by-n array B in which B[i,j] (for i =j, so it doesn’t matter what is output for these values.)
Here’s a simple algorithm to solve this problem.

```
For i=1, 2,...,n
    For j=i+1, i+2, ... n
        Add up array entries A[i] through A[j]
        Store the result in B[i,]]
    Endfor
 Endfor
```

(a) For some function f that you should choose, give a bound of the form O(f(n)) on the running time of this algorithm on an input of size n (i.e., a bound on the number of operations performed by the algorithm).

(b) For this same function f, show that the running time of the algorithm on an input of size n is also ~2 (f(n)). (This shows an asymptotically tight bound of ®(f(n)) on the running time.)

(c) Although the algorithm you analyzed in parts (a) and (b) is the most
natural way to solve the problem--after all, it just iterates through the relevant entries of the array B, filling in a value for each--it contains some highly unnecessary sources of inefficiency. Give a different algorithm to solve this problem, with an asymptotically better running time. In other words, you should design an algorithm with running time O(g(n)), where limn-->infinity g(n)/f(n) = O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go through the first part. Then, it will probably be clear enough for you to solve the second part. The third one is a completely independent question (and should therefore also be posted as a separate question if you need help with it).

To analyze the running time, we can start from the inside and gradually go outwards

```
Add up array entries A[i] through A[j]
```

Assuming the straight-forward implementation where you loop over the entries, this will give you a running time of `j - i + 1` (abstract time units). The exact number will depend on the implementation and how you count operations. For the `O(*)` notation, this will not make a difference. I will keep these specific times and will not simplify them to some `O(*)` notation since you will probably need the specific times for part (b).

```
Store the result in B[i,j]
```

This has a running time of `1`. Hence, the part inside the inner loop has a running time of `j - i + 2`. I will substitute the code with `T(j - i + 2)` onwards. So, the code we have left is:

```
For i=1, 2,...,n
    For j=i+1, i+2, ... n
        T(j - i + 2)
    Endfor
 Endfor
```

To find the running time of the inner loop, we need to solve the sum over the given bounds: `Sum (for j from i+1 to n) (j - i + 2)`. It is an arithmetic series with the solution `1/2 * (i - n - 5) * (i - n)`. The code is now:

```
For i=1, 2,...,n
    T(1/2 * (i - n - 5) * (i - n))
Endfor
```

Again solving the sum gives us the final running time of `1/6 * (n^3 + 6n^2 - 7n)`. And this function is in `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 0):

As summing of `A[i]` to `A[j]` is `j - i + 1`, `f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_j={i+1}^n (j-i+1) + 1` which `1` is for adding value to `B[i,j]`. Hence, by a change variable from `k = j - i + 1`, `f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=0}^{n-i+1}k = \sum_{i=1}^n (n-i +1)(n - i + 2)/2`. By change variable `h = n-i`, `f(n) = \sum_{h=1}^{n-i} (h + 1)(h + 2)/2`. Hence, `f(n) = n^3`. It means the algorithms is `O(n^3)`.

For the third part, you can use from this fact that `B[i, j] = B[i, j-1] + A[j]`. It means you can using from the previous computed sums to compute the forwarded sum. Using this fact, you change the `j - i + 1` to `1`. It means `g(n) = n^2` isntead of `n^3`.